# How to create a button in Unity 2021.3.3f1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, version

I am tying to follow this Unity course I found on Udemy. In the first part of the course, he teaches you to make a simple maze game that requires no coding. In one section he uses buttons that will control the game so we don't have to use code. He is using Unity 2021.1.? (I don't remember fully). In his video, he right clicks in the hierarchy -> ui -> button (in my version you have to go to legacy -> button instead) then a button appears in the bottom left corner of his screen which stays there even if you move the camera whereas in mine it just generates a 2d button in a random part of the screen and moves like a 2d sprite as it like a 2d rectangle which can change text and not a bottom that stays on my screen. Also the main camera can't see it. I understand the post is hard to read but all help is appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you're canvas is ScreenSpace Overlay. It won't move then.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your canvas is Screen Space Overlay, after that, you need to select your button and adjust your buttons position according to main camera.

Change your anchor presets to bottom right, then Adjust X & Y coordinates accordingly to place your button in bottom right corner of screen.

These settings worked fine for me (X=80 & Y=15) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).